# How to know the MAC address of the remote communication end?

Tags: networking, network-programming, linux-kernel, kernel-module

First, I need to know this in kernel space, so please take this into consideration.

No, I cannot use the IP address of the other device and ARP it(too long to explain why here) but I simply cannot use ARP, ARP won't work for the project I am working on.

Is there a function/utility I can use to know the MAC address of the other end in a connection attached to a given net_device I already have regardless of the IPs?

Thanks in advance, and if my question is not clear or makes no sense, leave a comment and I'll make sure to edit the question to explain/fill in the gaps

Comment: do you have access to the incoming packets? nefhook foe example.

Comment: I do have access to the incoming packets.
Currently I am saving the MAC addresses of the incoming frames to use them later for sending.
But is there another way to do this?

Comment: no, you either pre configure it or do it as you did. you can also look in the arp table but is seems more difficult to me to implement from kernel code.

Comment: How are you even communicating if you're not using ARP? You pre-filled the ARP cache?

Comment: Nope.
Well, I can't use ARP because I am changing the IP addresses that I am communicating with by hand(for another purpose that's out of the scope of the question) so if I ARP query the IPs, ARP won't find them or would find the wrong thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard protocol for "I need to speak to my neighbor" kind of problems is [LLDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_Layer_Discovery_Protocol). At the moment, this is usually implemented via OpenLLDP (user-space) on Linux systems. However, there appears to be some [kernel-space patches](http://lwn.net/Articles/503421/) on the way that might help you:

Supposing you have the possibility to enable LLDP on the other end, you should be able to use it to discover that device.